Conditional map in jq
Is there a way to use map() in a conditional manner ?
My problem is that I am using jq against Github repos.
Some repos (e.g. https://api.github.com/repos/containerd/nerdctl/releases) use prerelease flag and therefore I can use map(select(.prerelease==false))|first
Other repos (e.g. https://api.github.com/repos/slsa-framework/slsa-verifier/releases) do not and therefore map(select(.prerelease==false)) has no effect.
Therefore I need a way to conditionally check for the existence of .prerelease and if present apply map().

Other repos do not? Meaning, the prerelease field is present in both the JSON

If a key is not present, accessing it will produce null. You can use the fact that both false and null (and only those values) are falsey when evaluated in a boolean context. Turn them into true by using not where needed.

As an aside: map(‌select(…)) | first will perform the filtering on all items, to then discard all of them but the first. Instead, you could use first/1 to stop execution (the iteration in this case) as soon as one result is returned, i.e. first(.[] | ‌select(…)).

Are you looking for map(has("prerelease") && .prerelease == false))? It's not clear if you want to include or exclude objects missing the prerelease key.
